# In AngularJS, ng-model-options is not working when combined with a binding

Tags: angularjs

Why does *ng-model-options* with *updateOn: 'submit'* have no effect in the following scenario?

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <p ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}">Hello {{name}}!</p>
   <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
</body>
```

As soon as I change the text in the textbox, the text updates in the paragraph. I thought it was supposed to wait until the *submit* event fired before updating?

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fqNkgUMuQaUEID8hErQp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `ng-model-options` into the input element or in a **parent** element.

> All ngModel directives will use the options of their nearest
>   ngModelOptions ancestor.

Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Ah I see my confusion. In my case, I want elements outside of the p tag to update immediately. However, I want the inside of the p tag to only receive the latest model changes when a specific event occurs.

Comment: ok I understand your requirement, but it cannot work like this. `ng-model-options` describe how `ng-model` will update, its not about the element's binding.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angular Official Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) **You can specify that an ngModelOptions setting should be inherited from a parent ngModelOptions**

So, `ng-model-options` should either be given to input itself or its `parent`

To Input:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <p >Hello {{name}}!</p>
   <input ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}" type="text" ng-model="name" />
</body>
```

To Parent:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <p ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}">Hello {{name}}!
 <input  type="text" ng-model="name" />
  </p>
</body>
```

**Note:**
 You can specify that all undefined settings are automatically inherited from an ancestor by including property with a key of `"*"` and value of `"$inherit"`.

**Example:**

```
<div ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true, debounce: 200 }">
  <form ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur', "*": '$inherit' }">
    <input ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', "*": '$inherit' }" />
  </form>
</div>
```

the input element will have the following settings

`{ allowInvalid: true, updateOn: 'default', debounce: 200 }`

Notice that the `debounce` setting now inherits the value from the outer  element.